# Как изменить настройки docker-образа?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, docker

Когда создавал `image` написал сделующее в `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM ubuntu
```

Сейчас я понял, что было бы лучше сделать так:

```
FROM ubuntu
ENV LANG en_US.UTF-8
CMD ["/bin/bash"]
```

Могу ли я как-нибудь сделать такое изменение без потери содержимого в уже готовом `image` ?

Comment: вы хотите добавить `ENV` и `CMD`?

Comment: да.............................

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Сделайте новый Dockerfile и укажите предыдущий образ в директиве `FROM`. Таким образом вы добавите новый слой и создадите новый образ с вашими изменениями.

Comment: Образ назвать так же и запушить в тот же репозиторий ?

Comment: А что именно вы хотите получить?

Comment: Я хочу изменить текущий репозиторий на `docker hub`.

Comment: Тогда ответ - да.